# Connection drop by DB

Tags: mysql, hibernate, c3p0, amazon-aurora

I have a system with approximately 20 TPS. This system establishes DB connections to get some data. I am using Hibernate with c3p0 to manage my connections and Guice to ensure transactionality using the `@transactional` annotation.
Near about 0.3% of the request are failing because of some DB connection issue. 
This is what the stack trace looks like.

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not prepare statement
.
.
.
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not prepare statement
.
.
.
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed

.
.
.
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
.
.
.
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

My hibernate c3p0 settings are:

```
  hibernate.connection.url = "jdbc:mysql://dbHost.com:3306/DB";
  hibernate.dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect";
  hibernate.cache.provider_class = "org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider";
  hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = "update";
  hibernate.show_sql = "false";
  hibernate.connection.provider_class = "org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider";
  hibernate.c3p0.min_size = "100";
  hibernate.c3p0.max_size = "100";
  hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period = "100";
  hibernate.c3p0.max_statements = "0";
  hibernate.c3p0.timeout = "86400";
  hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery = "select 1";
```

My DB system variable:

```
connect_timeout=10
wait_timeout=86500
interactive_timeout=28800
```

These errors occur randomly, and when it is retried for the same input for which it initially failed it works.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: considering hibernate.c3p0.timeout = "86400"; Some database server are configured to close connections that are too old. Check your database server configuration. Or you can try to set a lower value.

Comment: I have added the system variable of the DB for some info.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to (hopefully!) address this is to add...

```
hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout = "true"
```

With your `preferredTestQuery` set, it's unlikely to be a performance problem. See [here](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#simple_advice_on_connection_testing) for some advice on Connection testing.